# Postman secrets in Hashicorp Vault

Tags: postman, hashicorp-vault, secret-key

Is there a way to pull secrets in Postman from Hashicorp Vault?
I see the feature is still open from 2018
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5577

Preferably without 3rd parties

Comment: If it was open source then you could easily use language bindings to do this yourself. Unfortunately, it is not open source.